Granting delayed access to query results in PostgreSQL
I'm building a system that allows users to queue batch jobs that execute a single query on the database, and process the results. Currently, the user supplies the username and password to be used by the system to authenticate with Postgres when creating a task. The credentials are stored base64 encoded in another database, and used (potentially hours later) to access the main database and execute the query.
I'd like to avoid storing the passwords beyond the initial task creation. Is there a good solution to this problem?
I've considered creating a view from the user-supplied query, and creating a temporary account that has select access on it. The credentials for the temporary account would then be stored, minimizing the damage if they are compromised. Does anyone know a better way?


How many users are we talking about? 2) Are the users limited in what tables they can access? 3) Why not have the queue table be in the main database, so the authentication takes place when the job is entered?


Thanks for showing interest! We're talking roughly 10 users, who will all queue a very similar query (differing in one condition) on the same set of tables. I want the queue table to be in the main database, but the problem is that the authentication would happen at the time of queueing a task, but I need it to happen potentially hours later at task execution time. Keeping an authenticated connection over that time is not an option, since the system may be restartem and lose it
